# Xamarin Forms Change label text in Frame

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created this frame:

```
<Frame BackgroundColor="Black" BorderColor="DarkGray" CornerRadius="20" HeightRequest="40" Padding="10,0,10,0">
    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Category_Clicked" />
    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
</Frame>
```

And in the code behind I have this event:

```
List<string> selectedCategories = new List<string>();
private void Category_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Frame frame = (Frame)sender;

    if (frame.BackgroundColor == Color.Black)
    {
        frame.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#2196F3");
        //Add label text to list
    }
    else
    {
        frame.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
        //Remove label text from list
    }
}
```

But I need to access the text from the label inside the Frame. How can I do that?

Comment: you are binding to `Name`, so just use the `Name` property of your VM

Comment: But I have multiple names, so multiple frames

Comment: You can get the Label inside `Frame` with `Content` property. Is pretty straight forward. Correct me if I'm doing it wrong (Any best practice rules I'm missing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `BindingContext`

```
Frame frame = (Frame)sender;
var item = (MyClassName)frame.BindingContext
var name = item.Name;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I did not know I could just bind it to my BindingContext, because it wouldn't know which I picked....

Comment: assuming this is a ListView, each row's BindingContext is set to the relevant item in the ItemsSource

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk If this worked then make sure to accept this as the answer

Answer (score 3):

Get the Label from `Content` property of `Frame`.

```
private void Frame_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Frame tappedFrame = (sender as Frame);
    Label childLabel = (tappedFrame.Content as Label);
    var resultText = childLabel.Text;
}
```

Works even if you don't know the type of `BindingContext`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Frame BackgroundColor="Black" BorderColor="DarkGray" CornerRadius="20" HeightRequest="40" Padding="10,0,10,0">
<Label x:Name = "MyTxt" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
<Frame.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Category_Clicked" />
</Frame.GestureRecognizers>
```

And in Code Behind:

```
if (frame.BackgroundColor == Color.Black)
{
    frame.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#2196F3");
    //Add label text to list
    MyTxt.text = "Some Text";
}
else
{
    frame.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
    //Remove label text from list
    MyTxt.text = "";
}
```